# Synchronization with Chain Of Responsibilities Design Pattern

Tags: design-patterns, synchronization, chain-of-responsibility

I have a big method in java, I want to break it into small small responsibilities, So as to use Chain of Responsibilities design pattern to make my code maintainable. Since my method is synchronized, can I still use Chain of Responsibilities with it?

Answer (score 0):

The Chain of Responsibilities Design pattern is used when we have to a sequence of tasks. The result of each task determines what the next task should be.

it is good to break down the "big method" but I don't see any relation with Chain of Responsibilities dp.